# How can I get permisson to delete files from a memory card?

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu I'm trying to delete some files from a memory card, but whenever I try to do so, I get a *Permission denied* error and can't delete them.

The files happen to be viruses so I need to get rid of them. How can I do that?

Comment: Not a programing question.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting them as super user, if you haven't yet:

```
sudo rm theFile
```